# AS3 vector projection on vector

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/vectors/tut03.html

Could you explain it to me, how do they get projection on vector? When I multiply dp * unit vector I get what? I don't understand what they do and how they get it without angles or anything else, just weird non-vector number*1-length vector getting from like 30k+ (I get huge dp numbers) anything like a projection. I really suffered enough going through all the formulas, trying to get a projection with atan2 and other geometry calculation.

Comment: Please don't include "Please, share a solution and very much appreciated explanation," "I could really use some help with this one," "pretty please," etc. in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a dot product of two vectors, divided by length of the vector that's being projected. You'll net the same if you normalize both vectors prior to projecting, and then multiplying the projection by length of the vector which is the projection base (sorry for bad English, my mind is slow). BTW, in orthogonal coordinate system you don't need angles to do projection - probably with non-orthogonal too. It's that the angle between vectors is derived from `acos(dotProduct(v1,v2)/length(v1)/length(v2))`.

```
var v:Vector.<Number>; // the vector to get projected
var p:Vector.<Number>; // the projection base. Lengths of vectors as number sequences are equal
function dotProduct(v1,v2:Vector.<Number>):Number {
    var d:Number=0;
    for (var i:int=v1.length-1;i>=0;i--) d+=v1[i]*v2[i];
    return d;
}
function lengthOf(v:Vector.<Number):Number { return Math.sqrt(dotProduct(v,v)); }
var pl:Number=dotProduct(v,p)/lengthOf(v)/lengthOf(p); // part of p's length that's the projection length
for (var i:int=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) v[i]=p[i]*pl;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you always help. But I don't get it. I hope you understand that I have lines, not really vectors? I change i to k (i used already), v1.length to vec1LEN, which I got via Pythagoras, d is dp. It wont work, output says error 1069. Why this wont work? var dp = vec1dx*vec2dx + vec1dy*vec2dy; I just need the shortest line between a dot and a line @ any angle >_<

Comment: Well, the shortest line from a dot to another line in 2D is the normal from that dot, and to get its value (you have origin) you need to make a vector that's orthogonal to your line, and project a vector from one of the points on the line to the dot to the normal. Perhaps you also didn't completely explain what do you really need, so you have received a vague answer.